# Executing SQL INSERT statement using .sql file based on condition using Oracle

Tags: oracle

I am looking for a SQL statement which executes based on a condition(code to run as .sql file)

eg:

```
declare          
v_cnt number;          
BEGIN          
    select count(*) INTO v_cnt FROM processtable a,datetable b where  a.date=b.date;          
    if v_cnt=0          
    then               
        Insert into processtable    
        select * from tableA    
        commit;    
    end if;      
end;    
/
```

Note: 
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed. But the v_cnt is always coming as zero and executes the insert statement. 
Please help me on this.

I execute the code in Unix as

```
sqlplus user/pwd@DBNAME;    
SQL> @filename.sql
```

Thanks
Karunya

Comment: What is the value of below query select count(*) FROM processtable a,datetable b where a.date=b.date;

Comment: It can be any integer value starting from 0. When I execute the select count(*) in the back end got "93" .

Comment: Please provide sample data from processtable and datetable and data type of columns in where condition. I believe column name should be different as DATE is reserved word.

Comment: you are right. date is not the exact field name. Issue here is v_cnt is not able to capture the value. From the back end I can see the value as "93"

Comment: Except for the reserved column name `date`, nothing looks wrong to me here. Maybe there is more than one schema containing those tables, and you are accidentally connecting to the wrong one.

Comment: yes it can be. But I prefixed my tablename with schemaname.

Comment: Date columns containing different times maybe?

Comment: If you're getting 93 from one session and 0 from another, and you are connecting as the same user for both sessions or are otherwise sure you're hitting the same schema's tables, then do you have uncommitted data in the first session?